# Not able to optimize query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT MIN(classification) AS classification
    ,MIN(START) AS START
    ,MAX(next_start) AS END
    ,SUM(duration) AS seconds
FROM (  SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN (duration < 20*60) THEN CASE WHEN (duration = -1) THEN 'current_session' ELSE 'session' END
              ELSE 'break' 
              END AS classification
            , CASE WHEN (duration > 20*60) THEN ((@sum_grouping := @sum_grouping +2)-1) 
              ELSE @sum_grouping 
              END AS sum_grouping
        FROM (  SELECT *
                    , CASE WHEN next_start IS NOT NULL THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, START, next_start) ELSE -1 END AS duration
                FROM (  SELECT id, studentId, START 
                            , (SELECT MIN(START) 
                               FROM attempt AS sub 
                               WHERE sub.studentId = main.studentId 
                               AND sub.start > main.start
                              ) AS next_start
                        FROM attempt AS main
                        WHERE main.studentId = 605
                        ORDER BY START
                    ) AS t1
            ) AS t2
        WHERE duration != 0
    ) AS t3
GROUP BY sum_grouping
ORDER BY START DESC, END DESC
```

## Explanation and goal

The `attempt` table records a student's attempt at some activity, during a session. If two attempts are less than 20 minutes apart, we consider those to be the same session. If they are more than 20 minutes apart, we assume they took a break.

My goal with this query is to take all of the attempts and condense them down in a list of sessions and breaks, with the start time of each session, the end time (defined as the start of the subsequent session), and how long the session was. The `classification` is whether it is a session, a break, or the current session.

The above query does all of that, but is too slow. How can I improve the performance?

## How the current query works

The innermost queries select an attempt's start time and the subsequent attempt's start time, along with the duration between those values.

Then, the `@sum_grouping` and `sum_grouping` are used to split the attempts into the sessions and breaks. `@sum_grouping` is only ever increased when an attempt is more than 20 minutes long (i.e. a break), and it is always increased by 2. However, `sum_grouping` is set to a value of one less than that for that "break". If an attempt is less than 20 minutes long, then the current `@sum_grouping` value is used, without modification. As a result, all breaks are distinct odd values, and all sessions (whether of 1 or more attempt) end up as distinct even numbers. This allows the `GROUP BY` portion to correctly separate the attempts into sessions and breaks.

Example:

```
Attempt type @sum_grouping sum_grouping
non-break                0            0
non-break                0            0
break                    2            1
break                    4            3
non-break                4            4
break                    6            5
```

As you can see, all the breaks will be grouped by `sum_grouping` separately with distinct odd values and all the non-breaks will be grouped together as sessions with the even values.

The `MIN(classification)` simply forces "current session" to be returned when both "session" and "current session" are present within a grouped row.

## OUTPUT OF `SHOW CREATE TABLE attempt`

```
CREATE TABLE attempt (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  caseId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  eventId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  studentId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  activeUuid char(36) NOT NULL,
  start timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  end timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  outcome float DEFAULT NULL,
  response varchar(5000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY id),
  KEY activeUuid activeUuid),
  KEY caseId caseId,activeUuid),
  KEY end end),
  KEY start start),
  KEY studentId studentId),
  KEY attempt_idx_studentid_stat_id studentId,start,id),
  KEY attempt_idx_studentid_stat studentId,start
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=298382 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What is the background? Explain the setup, which columns carry indexes? What are your ideas for optimization? Why do you think the current query is bad?

Comment: And add the tables structure, sample data, sample output you get, sample output you want to get.

Comment: @luksch current query is taking to much time to execute.

Comment: @suri Add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE attempt` to your question.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Please find the output:

Comment: @suri I have added an explanation of your query long with what I think your goal is. Please review and confirm whether or not it is correct. Such an explanation should assist in getting a good response from others.

Comment: @sun - Please provide sample output.  Given the stated goal, "sum_grouping" and having two "breaks" in a row do not make sense.  And there is no indication of student.  Or is that what the "sum" is doing?

Answer (score 1):

(This is not a proper Answer, but here goes anyway.)

Try not to nest 'derived' tables.

I see a lot of syntax errors.

Move from MyISAM to InnoDB.

`INDEX(a, b)` handles situations where you need `INDEX(a)`, so `DROP` the latter.

Comment: Also should adopt utf8mb4 instead of latin1

Comment: But not for UUIDs.

Comment: @RickJames I have added an explanation to the OP's question that may enable you to provide a fuller answer. I'm not experienced with user defined variables, so I am hoping someone more skilled, like you, or BillKarwin or ypercube or Rolando, etc, might be able to help.

Comment: @WillemRenzema - I can envision how to discover the breaks, but that should be done with "sessions" and "breaks"?  Let's see sample output.  I would expect "start-break" and "end-break" timestamps in the output??